# Connecting JcomboBox.getSelectedItem() to class

Tags: java, class, combobox, jcombobox

I have a combo box populated from an array (doesn't have to be). Once a selection has been made, I need to use that as a reference to a class (object of it) and return another object value.

```
public class MenuItem {

static int calories;
static int fat;
static int cholesterol;
static int sodium;
static int fiber;

MenuItem( int argCal, int argFat, int argChol, int argSod, int ArgFib) {

       calories = argCal;
       fat = argFat;
       cholesterol = argChol;
       sodium = argSod;
       fiber = ArgFib;
   }
}

public static MenuItem salad = new MenuItem(550, 13, 30, 860, 3);
public static MenuItem Chicken = new MenuItem(680, 13, 105, 1410, 4);
```

So, when they pick from `combobox`, I need to return "`cholesterol =105`" or "`cholesterol = 30`". My problem is I can't use `combobox.getSelectedItem()` to connect it to classes.

Comment: You probably have to cast it to MenuItem. Show the code for the listener.

Comment: Where is your `JComboBox`?

Comment: That`s the point, I dont have action listener... JComboBox is in the main[], just initiated and populated. Any ideas on the action listener?

Comment: If i understand this corectly, your combobox items are things like salad, chicken, and other stuff like this?

Comment: Yes, and when a user picks one, i am supposed to get the integer values using MenuItem.salad.getCholesterol...

Comment: I have a question for you: why do you make everything static? I strongly recomend you make MenuItem's fields private int.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you can do this.

```
comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if(selected.equals("Salad")){
            selectedCholesterol = salad.getCholesterol();
        }

        if(selected.equals("Chicken")){
            selectedCholesterol = chicken.getCholesterol();
        }
    }
});
```

Another way is to create a HashMap and put in in values when you populate the combobox. Something like this:

```
    map = new HashMap<Integer, MenuItem>();

    comboBox.addItem("Salad");
    map.put(0, salad);

    comboBox.addItem("Chicken");
    map.put(1, chicken);
```

And your listener would look something like this:

```
    comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Integer index = comboBox.getSelectedIndex();
            MenuItem mItem = map.get(index);
            selectedCholesterol = mItem.getCholesterol();

        }
    });
```

I like the second one more because it's listener is not going to be huge when you have more MenuItems.

Comment: Thank you, Cristian, the code for listener fully answers my question.